# Changing Makefile to ensure MEX points to matlab mex binary

Tags: 16.04, ssh, matlab, makefile

I have download a repository from the following link

[code repository](https://bitbucket.org/jaderberg/eccv2014_textspotting/downloads)

to run the code it is mentioned that  "**Edit matconvnet/Makefile to ensure MEX points to your matlab mex binary**."

[How to run code](https://bitbucket.org/jaderberg/eccv2014_textspotting)

So I opened the Makefile in vi and found following lines of code to edit

**Makefile contents**

[Makefile output in vi](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23490952/)

**Now my question is where to locate matlab mex binary path?**

**My effort**

I did  following command in my ssh shell environment

```
locate matlab | grep mex
```

[Output from Ubuntu](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23490937/)

Still not getting how to edit MEX path in Makefile so that it points to matlab mex binary also How to use ENABLE_GPU?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting.

Comment: If the output is very large, use http://paste.ubuntu.com